# Getting error with Cakephp 2.5.6 password hasher

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

My `AppController` -

```
App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');

/**
 * Application Controller
 *
 * Add your application-wide methods in the class below, your controllers
 * will inherit them.
 *
 * @package     app.Controller
 * @link        http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#the-app-controller
 */
class AppController extends Controller
{

    // Pass settings in $components array
    public $components = array(
                          'Auth' => array(
                                     'loginAction' => array(
                                                       'controller' => 'users',
                                                       'action'     => 'login',
                                     ),
                                     'authError' => 'You are not permitted for this action.',
                                     'authenticate' => array(
                                                        'Form'           => array(
                                                                             'fields' => array('username' => 'email')
                                                                            ),
                                                        'passwordHasher' => 'Blowfish'
                                     ),
                          'Session',
                         )
    );
```

And my `User` model. -

```
App::uses('BlowfishPasswordHasher', 'Controller/Component/Auth');

/**
 * This is a "Docblock Comment," also known as a "docblock."  The class'
 * docblock, below, contains a complete description of how to write these.
 */

class User extends AppModel
{
```

But i am getting error - `AUTHENTICATION ADAPTER "PASSWORDHASHER" WAS NOT FOUND`.
Cant find out the reason. What might be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in your array. Your Authenticate key should be this:

```
'authenticate' => array(
        'Form' => array(
            'fields' => array('username' => 'email'),
            'passwordHasher' => 'Blowfish'
        ),
    ),
```

The `authenticate` array key takes in an array of authentication mechanisms. The error you are getting is because CakePHP thinks there is an authentication system called `passwordHasher`.

Comment: no problem! It is what the community is here to do.